# Is there any way to install a bootable version of Ubuntu 12.04 to a usb?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, boot, usb

My laptop was having issues, so I had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu onto my usb (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), and now Steam is having issues opening. Is there any way that I can boot up Ubuntu 12.04 from a usb at this point? And if so, where should I get the iso?

Comment: This sounds like an xyz problem, you have x issue, you did y and now want to fix x with z.

Comment: why don't you focus on fixing the problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can get 32 bit and 64 bit iso from here

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

After getting this ISO you need to Create Bootable USB Drive in order ti install it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 images are available at: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/